# Webview App for all the Mobile Devices and uploading to play store

Tags: android, ios, webview, adk

I have a few queries about Webview app and uploading it to Play store-

There is a php/mysql webpage using javascript, css, html.

1) If we create a Webview app for this webpage using Android Development Kit, would the Webview App work only on Android phones even if its a plain webview ?

2) If not, what other platform is best to create a Webview app that works well on all the devices(Android, iPhone, Windows).

3) If the above webview app (created on ADK) doesn't work on all the devices (Android, iPhones, Window) and suppose the apk file is created using Android development kit initially and uploaded to play store with a key,  can the new webview app apk file be updated on palystore if we use another kit other than ADK (like PhoneGap, etc).

4) Is it possible that ADK Webview App doesnt work properly on all Andorid versions having some formatting issues. If yes, is there anything that we can add to work it well even in older android versions as well.

These queries might be very basic but I am new to Apps, so it woud be great if they can be replied with a brief description.

Comment: you should go for cross platform application development rather than native developement .There are many platforms available to develop a  cross platform app . You can get detailed information by googling it .

Comment: A web view app will be rejected by Apple; You cannot submit it to the App Store

Answer (score 0):

You can upload webView app in Apple AppStore with Authentic WebURL. you will need to submit information that define that you are the Owner of that Website. Otherwise it will be reject by Apple.

Comment: Same Webview created using ADK (since its for Android) can be used for Apple or any other method?